# How to filter XML Data in HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have an XML file and I loaded into HTML Table.

the Table have numbers as fields and that page contains two text boxes.. I need to filter the table with that textboxes as range from and to.

I need to filter the Html table before XML invoking.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

How about using the XSLT with your XML to filtering all you need, that would be enough. You can search the simple example here in [W3school](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [DOM methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM). They will work both on XML and HTML.